# C++: const-initialize multiple data members from one initializer function

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a C++ class with two data members, e.g.,

```
class mytest() {
   public:
     mytest():
        a_(initA()),
        b_(initB())
     {};
     virtual ~mytest() {};

   private:
     double initA() {
        // some complex computation
     }
     double initB() {
        // some other complex computation
     }

   private:
       const double a_;
       const double b_;
}
```

Unfortunately, though, `initA` and `initB` cannot be separated as sketched above. Both `a_` and `b_` can be initialized by one big complex computation, where the value of `b_` depends on an intermediate result in the computation of `a_`, e.g.,

```
void mytest::init() const {
   const double a = 1.0 + 1.0;    // some complex computation
   const double b = 2*(a + 1.0);  // another complex computation
   a = 2 * a;  // even more complex, wow
   // Now, a and b contain the data from which a_ and b_ should be initialized.
}
```

I would like to keep `a_` and `b_` separate (and `const`) variables (and not put them in a `std::tuple` or similar). However, I don't know if it's possible to initialize `a_` and `b_` separately from a single function.

Any hints?

Comment: well first you need to initilize those const members in the initializer list in the constructor, not in some member function

Comment: `a_` and `b_` should be initialize by constructor : `mytest(): a_(valueA), b_(valueB) {}` where `valueX` can be a direct value, a parameter from constructor, or a function returning calculated value. Also, having a function named `init` seams strange: when you instantiate an object, constructor will be called, and after that object is initialized. It's like having a function called `deinit` which should be called before destructor... no sense

Comment: Just initialize them in the initialization list. If you can't, then show some relevant code.

Comment: I see no need to make the members `const`. Could you please explain why you think this is necessary? As @Angew pointed out in a comment to my answer below, they prevent move-assignability and bring little benefit.

Comment: @Nasser I'm not sure how it matters that a type with two doubles is not moveable.

Comment: @juanchopanza you are right, but I'm commenting on the practice of creating const member variables, and for the types for which move-ability applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add extra intermediate function/struct to initialize your class

with delegating constructor:

```
struct MytestHelper
{
    double a;
    double b;
};

MytestHelper someComplexComputation(); // feed `a` and `b`

class mytest() {
   public:
     mytest() : mytest(someComplexComputation()) {}
     virtual ~mytest() {};

   private:
     mytest(const MytestHelper& h) : a_(h.a), b_(h.b) {}

   private:
       const double a_;
       const double b_;
};
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Add another example to the (long) list of "All problems in Computer Science can be solved by adding another layer of indirection (except too many layers of indirection)."

Comment: I won't be able to use the first suggestion since `b_` depends on an _intermediate_ result of `someComplexComputation()`. Delegating constructors will do, though.

Comment: Can I suggest removing the first suggestion?  The OP has clarified that he understands that approach, but that the calculation of the two variables are intimately connected, and can't be separated into two functions like that.

Answer (score 2):

What I will suggest may seem obvious, but there is absolutely no need to use `const` for your member variables. If you want your type to be immutable, simply do not provide setter methods, and compute the values of your members in the constructor.

```
class mytest() {
   public:
     mytest() {
         a_ = 1.0 + 1.0;    // some complex computation
         b_ = 2.0 *(a + 1.0);  // another complex computation
         a_ = 2.0 * a_;  // even more complex, wow      
     };

     // Make your methods const to prevent modification of the members
     void testMethod() const {
         // a_ = 20.0; // Will result in an error!
         std::cout << "sum = " << a_ + b_ << '\n'; // perfectly fine
     }

     virtual ~mytest() {};

   private:
       double a_;
       double b_;
};
```

This is much simpler, and achieves what you want.

Comment: you shouldn't allow people to modify things that shouldn't be modifiable I think, even yourself (I'm not the downvoter thought :-P )

Comment: I agree. `const` members are much more trouble than they are worth. They prevent move-assignability and bring little benefit.

Comment: @Guiroux Yes, but look at the complexity added by all the other answers!

Comment: @Angew totally agree

Comment: @Nasser the fact that other answers bring complexity don't imply that the actual best solution would, but yes I admit it adds complexity, but you can't say that other answer "proves" this, because it could be just terrible answers ...

Comment: My preference is to use `const` everywhere I can.  It makes it easier to reason about the variables (for me, and the compiler).  Most of my classes are explicitly not copyable or assignable anyway.

Comment: The code in the OP is of course a radical simplification of the actual code. That is so complex that `const` is needed to prevent developers from making the mistake of accidentally overriding the variables in question.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer if you make all of your methods `const`, then you will not be able to override those variables, rendering your type immutable. See the edit

Comment: That requires adding `const` to all methods which use `a_` or `b_`. Again, something that developers will definitely forget at some point.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I suppose that is possible, but it removes the complexity that's introduced with creating const member variables. All other answers so far (no offense) really pervert the code. Finally, I suggest that you have a little bit more faith in your development team, because if you can't trust them to make methods `const` for immutable types, then you're in for some real debugging fun as your project grows.

Answer (score -1):

You can always cast away the constness, but I would really reconsider your design rather than doing it.

```
// some pointer
double *ptr;
// give it the value of '_a'
ptr = (double*)( &_a );
// change the value now
*ptr = 5.34;
```

Also in your code

```
const double a = 1.0 + 1.0;
```

Should be

```
double a = 1.0 + 1.0;
```

No need for it to be const.

Comment: I'd say that `const double a = 1.0 + 1.0` should be `constexpr double a = 1.0 + 1.0`